# Opening taped boxes on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, boneh-soter, makeh-befatish

According to Halacha, is it permissible to open taped boxes on Shabbat? Or is this considered Boneh or Make B’patish or another type of prohibited melacha? On the other hand I could see them being designed to be temporarily taped structures so you’re not actually permanently altering them but using them as they’re supposed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rav Yehoshua Neuwirth's English translation of [Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasa Vol 1. 9:10 (p.93)](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/shemiras-shabbos-khilchasa-3-volumes/3299) writes as follows:

> Both
>
> a. cardboard boxes whose lids are stuck down with gummed paper or **tape** and
>
> b. boxes wrapped in paper which is stuck down with gum **may be opened provided the conditions specified in paragraph 12 below are fulfilled**.

Paragraph 12 (p.94) reads as follows:

> Even when it is permissible to open seals and wrappings, whether made of paper or some other material, the following conditions should be observed.
>
> **a.** 1) The seal or wrapping should be torn open in such a way that it is spoiled, and goes without saying that one must not intentionally tear it in a manner which leaves even part of it fit for any use (as where one tears carefully along the edge of prize tokens printed on wrapping).
>
> 2. This condition is equally applicable whether one is
>
> a) tearing the wrapping or seal itself or
>
> b) separating two pieces of paper or cardboard which are stuck together.
>
> **b.** One must not tear through lettering or pictures.